# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 Not making any sense?

Tags: java, arrays, list, indexoutofboundsexception

Here are my two classes:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TopoSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File textFile = new File("graphs.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(textFile);


        int numGraphs = in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
        {
            int nodeNum = in.nextInt();
            tsMakeGraph graph1 = new tsMakeGraph(nodeNum);

            int[][] adjArray = new int[nodeNum][nodeNum];
            for(int j=0;j<nodeNum;j++)
            {

                for(int k=0;k<nodeNum;k++)
                {
                    adjArray[j][k] = in.nextInt();
                }

                for(int n=0;n<nodeNum;n++)
                {
                    graph1.addNode(n);
                }


            }

            for(int j=0;j<nodeNum;j++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<nodeNum;k++)
                {
                    if(adjArray[j][k] == 1)
                    {
                        graph1.makeEdge(j, k);
                    }
                }
            }

            graph1.topologicalSort();

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;

public class tsMakeGraph {

    private Node nodeList[];
    private int adjMatrix[][];
    private int numNodes;
    private int topoArray[];

    public tsMakeGraph(int nodeNum) {
        nodeList = new Node[nodeNum];
        adjMatrix = new int[nodeNum][nodeNum];
        numNodes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeNum; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < nodeNum; k++) {
                adjMatrix[i][k] = 0;
            }
        }
        topoArray = new int[nodeNum];
    }

    public void addNode(int i) {
        nodeList[numNodes++] = new Node(i);

    }
}
```

I'm getting an out of bounds error when I add the nodes via a for loop but if I manually add the nodes via tying out graph1.addNode(0), graph1.addNode(2), graph1.addNode(3), graph1.addNode(numNodes), it will work. This doesnt make sense to me and I've been racking my brain haha. Btw I edited out most of my topo graph class cause this is a HW project.

Comment: You know from the exception traceback where the exception originates.  Add System.out.println calls just ahead of the failing operation to dump the array indices and the array .length values.  Something will surprise you.

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<1;i++)` <-- this won't take you very far... Copy/paste error?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. On what line does the exception occur? By the way the loop in tsMakeGraph's constructor that sets every element of adjMatrix to 0 is unnecessary; new numeric array elements are already 0.

Comment: Your j and n indexed for loops are nested in `TopoSort`, thus you're trying to add `nodeNum*nodeNum` elements to an array (graph1.nodeList) of size `nodeNum`. Use an ArrayList for nodeList instead?

Comment: @fge Well it will run once, perhaps he was just testing with a single iteration :) Please post the line of the error, that will make it much easier to pinpoint the mistake. This cannot be too hard to debug..

Answer (score 1):

Your j and n indexed for loops are nested in `TopoSort`, thus you're trying to add `nodeNum*nodeNum` elements to an array (graph1.nodeList) of size `nodeNum`.

You can eliminate a loop since you had two loops up to nodeNum from 0:

```
tsMakeGraph graph1 = new tsMakeGraph(nodeNum); 

int[][] adjArray = new int[nodeNum][nodeNum];
    for(int j=0;j<nodeNum;j++) {
        for(int n=0;n<nodeNum;n++) { // there was no need for two for loops here
            adjArray[j][k] = in.nextInt();
            graph1.addNode(n);
        }
    }
```

and make `nodeList` size `nodeNum*nodeNum`:

```
public tsMakeGraph(int nodeNum) {
    nodeList = new Node[nodeNum*nodeNum];
    adjMatrix = new int[nodeNum][nodeNum];
    numNodes = 0;

    //adjMatrix values will be 0 by default, don't need to manually do that

    // this might need to be nodeNum*nodeNum as well, not used in your question
    // if you get another out of bounds error later, remember this!
    topoArray = new int[nodeNum]; 
}
```

I also removed your manual setting of each value in adjMatrix to 0, as 0 is the default value anyway, and a O(n^2) operation could become quite expensive with a large number of nodes.

Perhaps consider using an ArrayList for nodeList instead (unless your homework prohibits this).  Actually, pulling the loop out from the j loop may be better, else you'll have `nodeNum` copies of each node.  Not sure of your usage, so I can't really help you there.

Keep in mind if nodeList is the wrong size, topoArray could be too.

Answer (score 1):

Shortening down the code a bit you have this:

```
for(int j=0;j<nodeNum;j++)
{
    for(int n=0;n<nodeNum;n++)
    {
         graph1.addNode(n);
    }
}

public class tsMakeGraph {

    public tsMakeGraph(int nodeNum) {
        nodeList = new Node[nodeNum];
    }

    public void addNode(int i) {
        nodeList[numNodes++] = new Node(i);
    }
}
```

So what is going on here is you have an array with `nodeNum` elements but you're trying to add to it `nodeNum^2` times.

I can't tell what the intent is to tell you the 'right' solution. If `nodeList` should have the same number of elements as `adjMatrix` then you should instantiate it like `new Node[nodeNum * nodeNum]`. (Same with `topoArray`?) Or if `nodeList` should contain the integers `0...nodeNum-1` then you should pull it out of the nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding nodes using this code:

```
for(int j=0;j<nodeNum;j++)
{
    for(int n=0;n<nodeNum;n++)
    {
        graph1.addNode(n);
    }
}
```

You are actually adding node nodeNum*NodeNum times. So for example if node num was 2, you are adding node 2*2 = 4 times.

However when you initialise the nodeList array like so:

```
nodeList = new Node[nodeNum];
```

You are only setting it to be of size nodeNum. So if nodeNum was 2, your array can only hold 2 values. But because of the code when you are adding:

```
nodeList[numNodes++] = new Node(i);
```

you are incrementing numNodes, 4 times. Which is causing the out of bounds error.

Initialising your nodeList array like so:

```
nodeList = new Node[nodeNum*nodeNum];
```

Should fix the issue